# Refresh Google Charts without redrawing the entire chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm creating a page where javascript creates random numbers and then draws a Google line chart from it. the idea is that data will continue coming and the chart has to be updated. What I'm doing right now is redraw the chart for every new data addition, which means redrawing the entire chart 20 times a second. This however slows down the process considerably.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to add a row to Google Charts and take out a row (like shift and push) and have the chart update without redrawing?

If that doesn't work do you guys have suggestions for live data visualization tools?

Answer (score 0):

Google charts are images served by Google's API.  There's no way to change just part of an image, you have to load a new image.  If you want a chart that changes, look at HighCharts.  It's a Javascript charting package that has examples like you want.  D3 also is very powerful, but requires more work.

Comment: There are two ways to use Google charts: Image Charts- Use the Google Chart API, Interactive Charts- Use the Google Visualization API (client code).  With both however, you must redraw the graph.  However, with client code, you don't need to make another trip to the server.

Comment: That's very useful. I wasn't even sure about the real difference between Charts vs. Visualisations. I'll go back and read more and check out HighCharts and D3 as well, Thanks!